# Backquote expansion in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, elisp, quote

I'm a Lisp beginner and I'm struggling to understand why the following code gives me an error.

```lisp
(dolist (elem '(mapcar
                mapcon))
  (when (fboundp `',elem) (print "hello")))
```

Thanks.

**Edit:**
A bit more context.  I wrote the following in Elisp and I don't know how to fix it.

```lisp
(dolist (ui-elem '(menu-bar-mode
                   tool-bar-mode
                   tooltip-mode
                   scroll-bar-mode
                   horizontal-scroll-bar-mode))
  (when (fboundp `',ui-elem) (ui-elem -1)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Note

In your question you mix `common-lisp` and `elisp`, but they are two different languages. The question however touches on concepts that are identical in both languages.

#### The need to quote symbols

The code you want to write checks if a symbol is bound to a function.
What you already know probably is that you can call `fboundp` on a symbol to determines this:

```
(fboundp 'menu-bar-mode)
=> t
```

When you evalute the above form, `'menu-bar-mode` is the same as `(quote menu-bar-mode)`, and is *evaluated* as the symbol object `menu-bar-mode`. This is the value that is given as an argument to `fboundp`.

In you example you want to iterate over a list of symbols, call `fboundp` on it and call the function if the symbol denotes a function. You can do this as follows:

```
(dolist (s '(menu-bar-mode and other symbols))
  (when (fboundp s)
    (funcall s -1)))
```

The list of symbols `'(menu-bar-mode and other symbols)` is quoted, which means that when `dolist` evaluates it, it sees a list of symbols. The value to which `s` is bound at each iteration of the loop is a symbol object, there is no need to quote them.

Quoting a symbol is something you have to do when writing them in your code so that they are not interpreted as variables. When you iterate over a list of symbols, you already manipulate symbols.

Note also that both Common Lisp and Emacs Lisp are "Lisp-2", meanings that you have to use `(funcall ui-elem -1)` instead of writing `(ui-elem -1)`. When you write the latter form, that means calling the function literally named `ui-elem` because for function application, the first symbol in the list is not evaluated, it is taken literally.

#### Too many levels of quoting

The actual error I have when I execute your code is:

> ```
> (wrong-type-argument symbolp 'mapcar)
> ```

It may look like `'mapcar` denotes a symbol, because when *you* want the interpreter to *evaluate* some code as a symbol, you need to quote it. However, Lisp printers write objects in a way that they can be **read** back to "similar" objects. The error message that is printed if I expect a symbol to be a number is the following, where symbol `foo` is printed unquoted:

```
(+ 'foo 3)

;; error: (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p foo)
```

In your error message, the form that you are trying to use as a symbol is  `(quote mapcar)`. Recall that when you directly call `fboundp`:

```
(fboundp 'mapcar)
```

It is the same as-if you wrote:

```
(fboundp (quote mapcar))
```

First, `(quote mapcar)` is evaluated, as the symbol `mapcar`. Then, `fboundp` is applied to that value.

But when you write the following, while `ui-elem` is bound to symbol `mapcar`:

```
(fboundp `',ui-elem)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
(fboundp `(quote ,ui-elem))
```

The argument to `fboundp` is **evaluated** as `(quote mapcar)`. You have one extra level of quoting. You could write instead:

```
(fboundp `,ui-elem)
```

But then, you don't need to use backquote/comma, you can directly write:

```
(fboundp ui-elem)
```